# Multiple optional parameters in MVC is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

My requirement is to provide optional parameters to urls. urls should be like the.

1. http://test.com/118939
2. http://test.com/118939/test/2000/

I have written following `routes`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new { favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?" });

            routes.MapRoute(
                "FAQDefault",
                "FAQ",
                new { controller = "FAQ", action = "Default" });
            routes.MapRoute(null, "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
            routes.MapRoute("rent", "{id}/{rent}/{unit}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional, rent = UrlParameter.Optional, unit = UrlParameter.Optional });
            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Default", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
                new string[] { "CDCPortal" });


        }
```

and controller written like:

```
 public ActionResult Default(string id, string rent=null,string unit=null){}
```

**Its working fine for 1 url but not working for second url.**

Comment: You should check the constraint code which you have provided in either of your routes, i think the constraint is failing and BTW `Default1` route is sufficient, there is not need of `Default` route.

Comment: What version of MVC do you use?

Answer (score 0):

**There is no need to do as, you have done in the first case:**

The `second route` can handle `any number of parameters`.

Comment: I have remove either of one but still not working for second case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a route for each combinations like below

```
routes.MapRoute("Default-AllOptional", 
                "Default/{id}/{rent}/{unit}", 
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Home",
                     action = "Default"
                     // nothing optional 
                 }
);

routes.MapRoute("Defaul-Id-rent-Optional", 
                "Default/{id}/{rent}", 
                 new
                 {
                     controller = "Home",
                     action = "Default",
                     id=UrlParameter.Optional,
                     rent=UrlParameter.Optional

                 }
);
```

Refer [`Routing Regression With Two Consecutive Optional Url Parameters`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/)

Comment: That bug was fixed in .NET 4.5

Comment: @MaxToro, Thank you. Not sure what version of MVC, OP is using. I got this problem in MVC 3

Comment: @krishnamenan, what was the solution?