# How to map route with two parameters value where the second parameter is optional?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am having trouble in route mapping. I have a `ActionResult` with two parameter where first parameter(category) is compulsory and second parameter(page no) is optional. Now I want to map a route that can work for url.

ie.

```
1). http://example.com/Blog/Category/programming
2). http://example.com/Blog/Category/programming/1
```

where the `programming` is category and `/1` is page no.

Here is my `ActionResult`:

```
public ViewResult Category(string category, int? p = 1)
{
    int pageNo = 1;
    if (p != null)
        pageNo = Convert.ToInt32(p);

    //other code    
    return View("Posts", myViewModel);
}
```

This is my mapped route:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Posts", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    //This route does not work    
    routes.MapRoute(
        "MyCategory",
        "Blog/Category/{category}/{p}",
        new { controller = "Blog", action = "Category", category = "", p = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Now, problem is that when I try to navigate page with both parameter its working fine. but, when i try without page no it gives me error "Server not found."**

[image]

I have also read some post where they have suggested some solution like this. But, still id doesn't work.

[Multiple optional parameters in MVC is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22507476/3761928)

Comment: have you tried overloading the method?

Comment: Show the route in context with your other routes.

Comment: Do you have another route that is picking up the same URL?

Comment: @AntP I have edited my question and shown whole `RegisterRoutes` method. I have just two route mapped and the first one is default route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/Blog/Category/programming` matches the first route (default), which should have no problem invoking the Category action on the Blog controller, except the `category` parameter would be null, because the third segment of the default route is the `id` parameter, not `category`. Do one of the following:

- Put the default route last
- Rename the `category` parameter to `id`

Comment: yes, you are right. It was taking default route by default. So, I have placed default route at last and now it is working fine. Thanks Max, you have solved my issue.